# C++/CLI Question about Timer Tick Event Trigger

Tags: forms, visual-c++, timer

I am new to C++/CLI and would like to disable a button for a short period of time after being pressed.
I've implemented a timer event but it is fired more times than I expect.  I have no idea about it.

```
         private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
         {
             timer1Count++;
             timer1->Stop();
             this->timer1->Enabled = false;
             MessageBox::Show("Timer1 Event Triggered.  timer1Count = " + System::Convert::ToString(timer1Count));
                     
             this->button1->Enabled = true;
         }

        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
        {
            this->button1->Enabled = false;
            this->timer1->Enabled = true;
            this->timer1->Interval = 2000;
            timer1->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::timer1_Tick);
            timer1->Start();
        }
```

The above is the core of my timer event.  My problem is

1. When I press the button1 first time, the timer1_tick function executes once.
2. When I press the button1 2nd time, the timer_tick function executes twice.
3. When I press the button1 3rd time, the timer_tick function execute three-times.
   ......

the number of times the event being trigger keeps increasing.
I would like to event triggered only once only I press the button.

BTW, my IDE is Visual Studio Community 2017.

Thank you

Daydream_eug

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by slightly modifying my code.  The final code is

```
         this->timer1->Interval = 2000;
         timer1->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::timer1_Tick);

         private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
         {
             timer1Count++;
             timer1->Stop();
             this->timer1->Enabled = false;
             MessageBox::Show("Timer1 Event Triggered.  timer1Count = " + System::Convert::ToString(timer1Count));
                     
             this->button1->Enabled = true;
         }

        private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
        {
            this->button1->Enabled = false;
            this->timer1->Enabled = true;

            timer1->Start();
        }
```

The key issue is the following line

```
timer1->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::timer1_Tick);
```

should be outside of the button1_click function.  If this line
is located inside the function, the timer1_Tick event is extra triggered.

Thank you

Daydream_Eug